# Understand usage of dagger2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I downloaded the [Coffee sample application](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple) and bring it into my IDE. After I run `mvn clean`, my IDE reports compilation error as:

[image]

And it won't get fixed until I run `mvn compile`. Obviously the sample code refers to some class that is generated by the tool.

I am quite surprised by this design as before you get the project compiled, you won't have a project that is ready to compile (looks like), kind of like you have to eat your own egg to get born.

Question: is this the normal usage scenario of dagger2? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Dagger makes use of the [Java Annotation Processing Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/), which hooks into the compilation process. During the annotation processing, the `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee` class is generated, *after* which the original and generated source code is compiled as a whole.

Needless to say, before compilation this class does not exist yet. That is why your IDE cannot find it, and marks it as an error. After running `mvn compile`, it can find the class.

Comment: Well that's not a good user experience. And how can I know that the class generated is named as DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee? Is there any naming convention?

Comment: Though it is not explicitly documented, [the documentation](http://google.github.io/dagger/) shows an example where a `CoffeeShop` `Component` results in a generated `DaggerCoffeeShop` implementation. So that is the original class name prepended with `Dagger`. Since a Major version has been released, it is highly unlikely this will change.